# Change content text language Umbraco for RTE

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, multilingual

New to Umbraco. I am trying to use shared pages for umbraco, and reuse the content text page in different langauge. Do we have any setting where we can change the text of the page or we need to create a new copy each time and then translate and write the content. Any help appreciated.

Edit:

After some research, I realized I need to dd custom plugin in Rich Textbox Editor for changing the language, so I can have  shared page and then use it across sites. These pages will have capability to change language and get the text accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use this package https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/vorto/ basically does all that for you instead of trying to create one yourself might as well use one that is tried and tested :).